# Concat Http Code with response body with Curl

Tags: http, curl

How do I merge/concat http_code along with http response body.
I'm using this  curl command:
curl -w "%{response_code}" --location -request POST *LINK*
I get output response body in Json and http_code in new line:
{response body}
400

But I want them both merged in same line, if possible, code first then body later.
Or else code appended within Json body.

Comment: I think you'll need to use a different tool than curl to accomplish this. For instance, try rewriting the command in python (using the requests module) and then add some code for manipulating the response into whatever format you want.